# PHP function file_get_contents($url) returns special characters

Tags: php, symfony, character-encoding, metadata, file-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve the meta data for a given links (url). I have implemented the following steps:

```
$url = "url is here";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$crawler = new Crawler($html); // Symfony library
$description = $crawler->filterXPath("//meta[@name='description']")->extract(['content']);
```

Doing so, I manage to retrieve the meta data for some urls but not for all.
Some urls, the file_get_contents($url) function returns special characters like (x1F‹\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03ì½}{ãÆ‘/ú÷øSÀœ'\x1E)! ‘z§¬qlÇI..........) that is why I could not retrieve the meta data.

Notice that, I am using the same website for $url values but passing different slugs (different blog urls like https://www.example.com/blog-1).

**Attempts:**

1. I used these functions  mb_convert_encoding and mb_detect_encoding
2. I made sure all urls I have passed are accessible through the browser.

Any thought, why I am getting special characters when I am calling file_get_contents function, and some time getting correct html format?

[image]

Comment: You tagged this with Symfony.  If you are indeed using Symfony then take a look at Symfony's HTTP client.  It can save you from many of the details for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Cerad what Symfony object/Library you are referring to?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the following parameters to file_get_contents functions:

```
private const EMBED_URL_APPEND = '?tab=3&object=%s&type=subgroup';
      
private const EMBED_URL_ENCODE= 'CM_949A11_1534_1603_DAG_DST_50_ÖVRIGT_1_1';
            
$urlEncoded= sprintf($url.self::EMBED_URL_APPEND, rawurlencode(self::EMBED_URL_ENCODE));
            
$html =  file_get_contents($urlEncoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output contains a mix of printable characters and escape sequences like "\x08" or "\x1E", which represent control characters or non-printable characters in ASCII or other character encoding schemes. The "x1F" at the beginning suggests that the data might be in a compressed or encoded format.

Try to decode $html variable with base64 or another way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @carlo-pokker This answer does not seem working. I tried this base64_decode($html), still returns special characters. Also I tried base64_decode($html, true) it returns false which means the input contains character from outside the base64 alphabet.

Comment: @IbrahimEL-Sanosi can you provide full example of that response string?

Comment: @carlo-pokker, Do you want to see the php code or full response?  if  you want to see full response, I do not think we can attach it here as the response is a thousand of lines of character encoding. I have added a part of the response as attached image in this post.

Comment: @IbrahimEL-Sanosi  not sure but you can try $file = fopen('' . 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($html), 'r');

Comment: @IbrahimEL-Sanosi or you can try gzdecode($html) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding the following parameters to file_get_contents functions:
     
private const EMBED_URL_APPEND = '?tab=3&object=%s&type=subgroup';
      
private const EMBED_URL_ENCODE= 'CM_949A11_1534_1603_DAG_DST_50_ÖVRIGT_1_1';
            
$urlEncoded= sprintf($url.self::EMBED_URL_APPEND, rawurlencode(self::EMBED_URL_ENCODE));
            
$html =  file_get_contents($urlEncoded);